# Modify the bash script so that after checking the type of the entity, it also lists the details of the input entity

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
PASSED=$1

if [ -f $PASSED ]; then
        echo "$PASSED is a file"
        ls -l $PASSED
elif [ -d $PASSED ]; then
        echo "$PASSED is a directory"
        ls -l $PASSED
else
        "$PASSED is invalid"
fi
```

At the terminal when I push a file input, say demo.sh, the output is correctly printed as:
"demo.sh is a file"
rwxr-xr-x  1 system  system  12 Jan 16 03:12 26 14:47 demo.sh

but for a directory, say cloud, it gives:
cloud is a directory
total 0

What should I do to rectify this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrC59.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output "`total 0`". Are you sure you are actually running the script shown in this question?

Comment: What does your script do for directories; you seem to have left something out. Also, what do you *want* it to do?

Comment: Do you want `ls -ld` on the directory? `ls -l` lists the contents.

Comment: What @BenjaminW. said.  If you run `ls -l cloud` and look at the output, you will see that you get a listing of the *contents* of cloud, and not cloud itself.  The first line is what you are getting (and not what you want).  If you run `ls -ld cloud`, you will get a listing of cloud itself, and not its contents.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I want to show the type of the input given as positional parameter and also it's permission details.

Comment: If the `-d` test is true, there shouldn't be any other output than what the `echo` prints at all. Is this your complete script?

Comment: @Socowi yes, I wrote that script myself and ran it. It works fine for the files, but is not working for the directory.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, this is the complete script. I am very new to BASH scripting and would be great if you can check if the script itself is correct as well.

Comment: Have a look a https://www.shellcheck.net/ for automated pointers to best practices such as quoting variable expansions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown from the man pages for ls:

```
   -d, --directory
          list directories themselves, not their contents
```

With your current implementation, as you are using just -l with your directories, ls will show the contents of the directory. To list the properties of the directory only, use -d in addition to -l and so:

```
ls -ld $PASSED
```